# How to access Heroku Config Vars in Bash

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to use `process.env.REACT_APP_*` process env variables in my react app after building it with `npm run build` on heroku, but my setup has a server and a client with all of the react code in a separate client folder in the root:

```
root
└ client/
  └ build/
└ server.js
```

Even in my local development server this isn't working properly and I'm having to use a separate .env file in the client with the same key/value pair just prepended with `REACT_APP`. On my local, I'm running the server and the client concurrently, but on Heroku, it's built into a static app under `client/build`. The config vars that I defined on the heroku site is evidently not accessible in the static app because when I console log the process.env variable, I only see these variables:

```
NODE_ENV: "production"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

I have several `REACT_APP_*` variables defined on the heroku site, but none of them make it to the static build, but they're perfectly accessible on the server.

I need a way to access the variables on the static site and I'm currently exploring the possibility of manually writing a `.env` file to the client folder via bash scripts before running `npm run build`, but I ran `compgen -v`and `set` and viewed the values of all of those variables and the config vars don't appear to be any of them.

EDIT: I want to also note that I've tried this on a static-only heroku deploy which does NOT have a server and the root folder is the react app itself and I'm able to see my config var when I console.log(process.env):

```
NODE_ENV: "production"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
REACT_APP_TEST: "HELLO WORLD"   <<===========
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

When heroku runs "npm run build", it is actually building the server.js file. Hence, the environment variables are injected in to server.js. If you console.log them some where inside the server.js, you will have them. The client is not actually build using the heroku, so no environment variables are injected. This is normal. You can change your project folder structure to fix this.

Comment: my build script in the root is to cd into the client and run the build there:
```
"build": "cd client && npm run build"
```

So I'm asking what options I have to send the process.env variables to the client before building. I just need to know how to access them in bash and I can write a script to do it.